# LEGO part 3039 black with red sticker

Tags: sticker-identification

[image]

Wondering what set this came from.

Answer (score 6):

After cross-referencing Part 3039 with the crystal piece shown on the sticker, [Part 52](http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=52&idColor=108#T=C&C=108), in each shade of green, I found it: [Clash of the Heroes](http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=76044-1#T=S&O=%7B%7D) from the Batman vs. Superman sets. The sticker itself is sheet [76044stk01b](http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=76044stk01b&idColor=0#T=C&C=0).

Comment: http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=76044stk01b&idColor=0#T=C&C=0 is the sticker itself.

Comment: @chicks Whups, let me add that!